# Online screenshot tool focusing mobile, tablet, notebook resolution?

Tags: android, iphone, screenshot, tablet

I have developed a small HTML5/jQuery site. This site is deployed online. For documenting purposes *(github..)* I need a Website which:

must have

- take screenshots
- is configurable to support the three screen resolutions mentioned above.

nice to have

- embedding the screeny in smartphone, tablet and (notebook) graphical frames
- is free :-)

I have a HTC Desire HD, on which my site looks good. I want to show my visitors that the site looks good on these tree device classes.

I have searched intensely.

Answer (score 0):

3 out of 4: [Browshot](https://browshot.com/) and [Mobilito](http://mobilito.net/)